# Very unlikely vs. unlikely in French

Tags: traduction, adjectifs, adverbes

Comment dit-on « very unlikely » en français?  Je veux l’utiliser dans une échelle de Likert, et c’est nécessaire de contraster « very unlikely » avec « unlikely ».

J’ai considéré quelques alternatifs, mélangeant une combinaison de *très*, *vraiment*, et *fort* avec *peu probable* et *improbable*.  Malheureusement, quand on recherche ces phrases sur google.fr, on ne les voit pas souvent sauf sur les sites qui essaient de traduire « very unlikely » entre anglais et français. Cela me fait penser que ces phrases ne sont pas vraiment naturelles.

---

What's the appropriate way to translate very unlikely into French?  This is being used in a Likert scale (*very unlikely*, *unlikely*, *neither likely nor unlikely*, *likely*, *very likely*).

I can think of several alternative translations, with some combination of *très*, *vraiment*, *fort* for "very" and *peu probable* or *improbable* for "unlikely."  However, most of the google.fr searches I find for any combination of those phrases seems to be sites that are examples of them being translated from English — not examples of these phrases being in use.  This makes me suspicious that those phrasings are fairly unnatural.

It's notable that this needs to be contrasted with a less extreme version of unlikely, e.g., either *peu probable* or *improbable.*

Comment: Shouldn't it ne "Quand on récherche ces phrases..." as opposed to "Quand on *cherche* ces phrases..." ? Fix my edit if I'm partially mistaken there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Peu probable** et **improbable** sont tout à fait corrects. **Très probable** et **fort probable** le sont aussi mais je pense qu'il est difficile de discerner lequel des deux serait à placer avant l'autre sur l'échelle.

En revanche, **vraiment probable** sonne un peu moins naturel selon moi.